# How do I pass a URL segment to a search parameter?

Tags: search, archives

I'm trying to set up an archive page by passing dates in the URL to the entries search parameter to show events from a specific month.  The `eventstart` is a custom date field.  If I enter numbers i.e. 2017-11 in the search parameter it works but the URL segments don't seem to parse.

Thanks in advance.

```
{% set year = craft.request.segment(3) %}
{% set month = craft.request.segment(4) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('calendar').search('eventstart:"year-month)"') %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    <h3><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use Twig's [string concatenation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) in order to do this with the `~` operator.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('calendar').search('eventstart:' ~ year ~ '-' ~ month) %}
```